# Profiling Scala code for Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jvm, profiling, large-data

I'm new about Scala and large dataset programming. I need to use a profiler in a local environment, in order to inspect which operation/function is too slow in my Scala code, I tried a Spark UI both in local node and in a cluster environment, but it's not sufficient.  The problem is that my code is a Scala "script", or better it is only a sequence of code lines executed directly in a spark-shell.

All common profilers require well structured Scala code in order to generate a jar file and run the jar file to attach the profiler agent.
I don't know where to search. Any ideas? Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach Java profilers (e.g. the free `jvisualvm` that comes with the JDK) to any running JVM. I have not tried it, but I believe that you should be able to profile code that gets executed by Spark.

Of course, you have to connect to the right JVM where the code is executed. If it is executed remotely, it won't help to connect to the local JVM running your Spark shell.

You also have to make sure to profile at the right moment.

Comment: Thanks, I used YourKit in "attach mode". Simple UI and fast.

Comment: @user7331766 If I answered your question, you can mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: @user7331766 I tied to mark your question, but I received a message your feedback is recorded.

Comment: @user7331766 Hmm, I think you did something wrong. There should be a white check mark `✓` below the score with the up/down buttons left of my answer. If you click it, it turns green and makes my answer the "accepted answer" for the question.

Comment: @user7331766 do you have a reference link for YouKit used this way by any chance?